# "How to write a program in Pascal?" vs "I know how to write a program in Pascal"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, questions

Am I right that we use the same wording to ask a question and to to state something (not a question), when we use "how"?

> **How to write a program in Pascal**?
>
> I know **how to write a program in Pascal**.

Comment: Effectively, *No, you're not right.* Your text *How to write a program in Pascal* isn't a question. It's effectively a special kind of ***noun phrase***, syntactically the same as the highlighted element in *He knows **the English language***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to write a program in Pascal?

Is not a usual or optimal way to phrase a question. Better would be:

> - How do you write a program in Pascal?
> - How does one write a program in Pascal?
> - How does a person write a program in Pascal?

In short the verb "write" should have a subject. Various other constructions are posisble with much the same meaning, of course.

In a construction such as:

> How is a program written in Pascal.

the statement is inverted, compared to the question, although "how" is used:

> I know how a program is written in Pascal. (Technically it is the question that is inverted.)